# On variable value change.

Tags: c#, variables

I have some code which sets a variable depending on different inputvalues. Simplified here:

```
if (hipDepthPoint.X < 100)
{
    Xvariabel = 1;
}
else 
{
    Xvariabel = 2;
}
```

Then I want to look for changes in the variable `Xvariabel`, and whenever the value changes I want to perform an action. I have looked into events and properties, but I couldnt make any of them work.

Comment: Where do you want to check if it has changed? Is this the only place it can change?

Comment: This is the only place it can change. Preferably check the value for changes in a new method or function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to do it with a property

```
if (hipDepthPoint.X < 100)
{
    Xvariabel = 1;
}
else 
{
    Xvariabel = 2;
}


public int Xvariabel 
{
    get { return _xvariabel ; }
    set
    {
        if (_xvariabel != value)
        {
            _xvariabel = value
            //do some action
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That worke very well! I just had to declare _xvariabel as an int to get it all to work perfectly.

Comment: @cse Would you mind marking it as an answer if you are all happy! So if someone stumbles upon this question in future, they know where to look.

Answer (score 1):

Properties with setter should do the work.
you should write something like that:

```
private int _X     
public int X {
    get { return _X ; }
    set { _X  = value; //Your function here }
}
```

Comment: That's missing a check to see if it's actually *changed*. Setting X to the same value twice will call `your function here` when it shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example what you can do using an invention and power of .net.
I used INotifyPropertyChange, but you can use your own interface. This is very universal type, that will notify its own value change to multiple listeners

```
public class Test
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ObservableVar<int> five = new ObservableVar<int>(5);
        five.PropertyChanged += VarChangedEventHanler;
        five.Value = 6;
        int six = five;
        if (five == six)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You can use it almost like regular type!");
        }
        Console.ReadKey();            
    }

    static void VarChangedEventHanler(object sender,PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} has changed",sender.ToString());
    }
}


public class ObservableVar<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private T value;

    public ObservableVar(T _value)
    {
        this.value = _value;
    }

    public T Value
    {
        get { return value; }
        set
        {
            if (!this.value.Equals(value)) //null check omitted
            {
                this.value = value;
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Value"));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


    public static implicit operator T(ObservableVar<T> observable)
    {
        return observable.Value;
    }
}
```